# Using javascript, how can I set map mode of Bing map rendered via Silverlight?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, dictionary, bing, mode

I have googled a lot but have failed to find answer to this problem,
Problem:
I am loading a Bing map as specified in this MSDN tutorial:
[Incorporating Map Functionality using Script]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681891.aspx)

Now map loads correctly but inside "onSilverlightLoadedHtml" js function, when I try to set its mode using following js statement, it gives me error:
map.mode = "aerial"

Error that shows on firebug is following:
uncaught exception: Object doesn't support this property or method

I have searched a lot but majority resources on Bing map Silverlight are in XAML or using some server side coding. 
But can anybody tell, how can I achieve my goal through javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Well....I spoiled my whole day looking for some resolution to my mentioned question, but found nothing and now just after posting it on stackoverflow, I thought to give it an another try and yes....bingo....it worked this time.
Here is the solution:

function onSilverlightLoadedHtml(plugIn, userContext, sender) {

var slCtl = document.getElementById(plugIn.id);

var mode = slCtl.Content.services.createObject("Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.AerialMode");

slCtl.Content.map.Mode = mode;

}